# Why mongodb find() never got to my callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying build rest-like API using mongodb(with mogoose) and node.js with restify.
I'm an absolute novice in the mongo world, and I'm not sure where problem is. Is this the db connection's problem, or something else?

So, I'm doing it this way:
**rest-server.js**

```
//start server
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

//connect db
var config = require('./Config.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),   
db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'travelers'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
ObjectId = mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('db connection open');
});

var LoginModel = require('./models/LoginModel.js').make(Schema, mongoose);
var LoginResource = require('./resource/LoginResource.js')(server, LoginModel);
```

**LoginModel.js**

```
function make(Schema, mongoose) {
    var LoginSchema = new Schema({
        //id: (?)
        username: String,
        password: String,
        traveler_id: Number,
        contact_id: Number,
        last_login: Date,
        token: String
});
    return mongoose.model('Login', LoginSchema);
}

module.exports.make = make;
```

**LoginResource.js**

```
exports = module.exports = function (server, LoginModel) {
    var LoginRepository = require('../repository/LoginRepository.js');

    server.get('/login/:username/:password', function (req, res, next) {    
        LoginRepository.getLogin(req, res, next, LoginModel);
    });
}
```

**LoginRepository.js**

```
function getLogin(req, res, next, LoginModel) {
    var query = LoginModel.find({ username: req.params.username, password: req.params.password});

    query.exec(function (err, docs) {
        console.log('got it!');
        res.send(docs);
    });
}
```

test query
**curl localhost:8080/login/qqq/www**

So I never got to `res.send(docs);`
Actually, I didn't add anything to the db. I just want to know that the query didn't find anything.

**UPDATE:**
I don't understand why, but this problem can be solved if I change the db connection code like this:

```
//connect db
var config = require('./Config.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose/');
db = mongoose.connect(config.creds.mongoose_auth),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

(use **mongoose.connect** and define **db** and **Schema** vars as global)

but in this case **db.on()** and **db.once()** throw an exception "no such methods".

In other words - problem mmm... solved but I still don't know why.
This looks like a helpful link: [server.js example on github](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/blob/gh-pages/examples/nodejs-mongodb-mongoose-restify/server.js)

Comment: Also i'm launch mongo like that: **mongod -dbPath ../data/db**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Models that you've created by calling `mongoose.model()` use Mongoose's default connection pool when executing queries.  The default connection pool is created by calling `mongoose.connect()`, and any queries you make using your created models will be queued up until you call that and it completes.

You can also create separate connection pools (that can have their own models!) by calling `db = mongoose.createConnection()` like you were originally doing, but you would have to create the models for that using `db.model()` which is why things weren't working for you originally.

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to fix the issue I was having!